# How to override abstract block app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Abstract.php and app/code/core/mage/Controller/Abstract.php

Tags: wishlist, magento-1.4

1. In Controller `Abstract.php` file, I want to override the 
   `public function allcartAction()` to add one more parameter to `$item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner))` 
   ie to change the function as $item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner,$params))
2. In Block/Abstract.php file I want to modify the `public function getWishlistItems()`
   { function to remove the visisbility filter

So instead of overriding the files to `app/code/local/Mage` folder, is there any nice way of doing it

Comment: Girish SH,Abstract is not Override .Only solution is copy to local folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you should not be overriding Abstract classes.  When you override in the `app/code/local/Mage` folder, you are locking that file into it's particular version.  Now you must maintain that file separately and you risk breaking upgrades.

Try to think of a different approach instead of an abstract override.

How about controller rewrites?

```
<!-- Magento 1.4 controller rewrites -->
<global>
    <routers>
        <wishlist>
            <rewrite>
                <index>
                    <actions>
                        <allcart>
                            <to>custom_route/your_controller/overriding_action</to>
                        </allcart>
                    </actions>
                </index>
            </rewrite>
        </wishlist> 
    </routers> 
</global>
```

If you rewrite `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController` (for example) and override only those methods you need changed, you can then maintain compatibility.

Is this the easiest way?  No.  But it is the ***right*** way to maintain maximum upgradability.